# Laravel 10: In Api response I am getting some script response

Tags: laravel

I have create an admin panel using laravel 10, and create API. It is working fine until yesterday, now I am getting some script before the response. I have secure the API using auth token.

How can I fix this issue?

This is the response:

[image: Postman Response Image]

Comment: what does sanitizing the html have to do with an api response?

Comment: Can you please share the Api code (the code in controller ) for this request ?